# Linux Kernel Path and compression

Tags: kernel, boot, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to find the Linux kernel path to find out what kind of compression it uses in a industrial Raspberry Pi.

I'm running the command `cat /proc/cmdline` and get the output:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 smsc95xx.macaddr=18:83:C4:04:49:C5 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait noinitrd elevator=deadline bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080
```

The content of `/boot` is (the Linux kernel image should be here):

```
total 24948
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   15747 Jul 31  2018 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3667 Jul 31  2018 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dts
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   50192 Feb 10  2017 bootcode.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     391 Oct  7  2019 boot.scr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     136 Jan  1  1980 cmdline.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     103 Jul 31  2018 config.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       4 Oct  7  2019 console_status
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   18693 Aug 21  2015 COPYING.linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   39946 Jul 31  2018 dt-blob.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   62963 Jul 31  2018 dt-blob.dts
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2527 Nov 25  2016 fixup_cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    6617 Feb 10  2017 fixup.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    9751 Nov 25  2016 fixup_db.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    9749 Nov 25  2016 fixup_x.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     512 Jan  1  1980 FSCK0000.REC
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     512 Jan  1  1980 FSCK0001.REC
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     512 Jan  1  1980 FSCK0002.REC
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     512 Jan  1  1980 FSCK0003.REC
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     145 Nov 25  2016 issue.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4228952 Feb 10  2017 kernel7.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4128712 Nov 25  2016 kernel.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1494 Nov 18  2015 LICENCE.broadcom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   18974 Nov 25  2016 LICENSE.oracle
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    8192 Jul 31  2018 overlays
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  633636 Nov 25  2016 start_cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4954692 Nov 25  2016 start_db.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2830532 Feb 10  2017 start.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3904260 Nov 25  2016 start_x.elf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     512 Feb 10  2017 System Volume Information
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     383 Jan  1 01:00 tb_config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35700 Jan  1 01:00 tb_config_tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     391 Jul 31  2018 tmp_boot.cmd_servic_off
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     438 Jul 31  2018 tmp_boot.cmd_servic_on
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  340632 Feb 10  2017 u-boot.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4228672 Feb 10  2017 zImage
```

But I don't see relationship between them... Can someone help me identify the image and explain the output of the command `cat /proc/cmdline`?

**UPDATE**

In my laptop with Arch Linux the relationship is clear:

Input: `cat/proc/cmdline`

Output: `BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=[...] rw quiet`

And in `/boot` I can find:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6289792 oct 18 02:15 vmlinuz-linux`

Comment: For the latter, `man proc` and look for `/proc/cmdline`. For  the former, I would guess `zImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the file called `zImage` in the bottom of your listing.

If I am not mistaken that is a `gzip` compressed kernel image which the boot loader loads.

The best reference I found on a quick search is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux.

If anyone has better reference feel free to edit or comment.

Comment: oh, zImage is the linux image?

Comment: Could you know how you came to that conclusion? (I mean compression `gzip`) Is there any way to see what type exactly?

Comment: I learned that in a certification training, but you can probably find it somewhere on the internet. The best can I can find with a quick search is wikipedia though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux.